# How to update the remove item in checkout/cart section?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, checkout, cart, mini-cart

I am new user of Magento and  added remove_item link near quantity block at grouped product section at each product in grouped product.

The item get removed at grouped product page but when i proceed to cart page by clicking add-to-cart page then it not updated the cart.

It again showing the removed item on cart page. But I don't want removed item on cart page.

Please anyone suggest me how should i overcome this problem.(I want same functionality like minicart remove_item link proceed).

Please suggest me suitable solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following custom code in grouped.phtml of path:
app\design\frontend[your_theme]\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\grouped.phtml

Below qty code:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Remove This Item')) ?>"
          data-confirm="<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>"
           class="remove">
       <?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>
    </a>
    <!-------End of custom code------->
```

and in same file added the following script to remove product:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
jQuery('.remove').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).prevAll('input').val(0);
    jQuery(this).closest('tr').hide();
    //alert(jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('td').html());

})
```

})

This code remove the product from product page as well as from checkout, from grouped product list.